# Can I use a class with a generic type to a collection of a different class?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following generic class:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private String name;
    private T value;
    ... // get/set methods
}
```

In another class I want to have:

```
public class Bar {
    private List<Foo> list;

    public <T> Foo<T> getFoo(String name) {
        // find elem which matches the name
        return listElement;
    }
}
```

I guess there is not connection of what `T` is referring to in the `getFoo()` signature. IntelliJ is complaining about an unchecked assignment. I cannot do `List<Foo<T>>` because `T` doesn't exist in the context of the `Bar` class.

Can this be done, or am I misusing the whole concept of generics in this case?

Comment: can you put <T> behind getFoo, likewise do getFoo<T>(String name) ?

Comment: because `Foo` is a rawtype, you´d need to define it as `List<Foo<Whateveryourclassis>>`.

Comment: And if you like to keep the T you need to add it to Bar<T>... List<Foo<T>>

Comment: adding to @KevinEsche's point, you could also have a generic on `Bar`, then you could have `Bar<T>` and `List<Foo<T>> list`.

Comment: `Bar` doesn't know what `T` is. `Bar` actually represent a repository of `Foo` objects. Therefore I find it wrong to do `Bar<T>`.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve sounds like a variant of of a type-safe heterogeneous collection, as discussed in Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 29.

Comment: @sisyphus I had a look into Item 29. The proposed solution was Map<Class<?>, Object>. I just have a List in my case and many objects might be of the same type. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will also need the class. Because of type erasure.

```
public class Bar {
    private List<Foo<?>> list;

    public <T> Foo<T> getFoo(Class<T> type, String name) {
        // find elem which matches the name
        return type.cast(listElement);
    }
}
```

The conclusion is, such a property wrapper makes no sense for a getter by name. A getter by class, say by interface might be more interesting.

Comment: `Foo` in reality has `Class<T>` in it. But I don't want the caller of `getFoo()` to know the class. Is there a way to 'cast' it from inside `getFoo()`?

Comment: Then `Object getFoo()` or some interface parent of T is all what is possible.

Comment: However the cast might be used, but probably is redundant, as the adding to the list could be parametrized.

Comment: @DimitriosK. then it sounds like the return type of `getFoo` should be `Foo<?>`.